# Unable to share Image using FIle Provider java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-permissions, android-fileprovider

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
> androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri
> content://com.jjdj.jdjjd.jdjjdj/sdcard1/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Paintings/Painting_440.png
> from pid=27901, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or
> grantUriPermission()
> at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:740)
> at android.content.ContentProvider.semEnforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:659)
> at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:602)
> at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceFilePermission(ContentProvider.java:593)
> at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:507)
> at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:307)
> at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
> at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)

Below code has been used for this:

```
private fun share(fileName: String) {
    val shareFile = File(getStoragePath(), fileName)
    val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, SHARED_PROVIDER, shareFile)
    val intentBuilder = contentUri?.let {
        ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
            .setType("image/*")
            .addStream(it)
    }
    val chooserIntent = intentBuilder?.createChooserIntent()
    activity.startActivity(chooserIntent)
}
```

provider passed in manifest :

```
  <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.jsjsj"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

Path Xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="Paintings"
        path="Paintings/" />
    <external-path
        name="Paintings"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="Paintings"
        path="." />
    <!-- FOR SD CARD-->
    <root-path
        name="sdcard1"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. This was what I ended up doing, it's set up a little differently than yours but hopefully its helpful.

```
                val myBitmap = //create a bitmap here

                val file = File(activity.externalCacheDir, "myFileName.png")
                val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, fileOutputStream)
                fileOutputStream.flush()
                fileOutputStream.close()

                val fileProviderUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.applicationContext.packageName
                        + ".provider", file);
                
                val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
                    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileProviderUri)
                    type = "image/png"
                }

             
                val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)

                if (shareIntent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager) != null) {
                    context.startActivity(shareIntent)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error Occurred Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
```

Manifest provider

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,I  will try this